# Android touch event stucked in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-touch-event

I have a container `View` that should process touches. It has `Listview` with overrided `onTouch()`, which returns `false` (it will return `true`, when container is expanded by swipe). When `Listview` touch occurs it passes to container `View` and everything is ok. But I need to add click handling for items of `Listview`.

When I set `onClickListener` for item, I see in logs it is no `MotionEvent` passed to container, it is stucked in `ListView` `onTouch()` (which return `false` and does nothing). I'm trying to set `onTouchListener` for item like this:

```
    viewHolder.itemLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    return false;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "something like click detected");
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But result is the same. Can someone explain why my container does not receive touch event even `ListView` returns `false` for its overrided `onTouch()`?

Comment: I believe you can directly use OnItemClickListener to handle click on listview items

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to handle the clicks of ListView items : **use OnItemClickListener**

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //parent.getItemAtPosition(position) returns the value of item clicked.. use it to do whatever you wish to do
        }
    });
```

Comment: the real problem is to pass touch event from listview to its container after we decide this event is not interested for us in listview item.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem about 2 weeks ago. Returning false from listview's onTouch method did not pass event to parent container. I ended up doing this:
1. You need custom layout for your container `View`. Then in that view, override onInterceptTouchEvent, for example like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch  (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                previousX_actionDOWN = ev.getRawX();
                isOnClick = true;
                timePressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
                return false;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (isOnClick && (Math.abs(previousX_actionDOWN - ev.getRawX()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!wasDragged) {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I also have complicated onTouch method in that view but it's not worth pasting. Point is that your parent view should only intercept touch event if some threshold was passed while ACTION_MOVE - well at least that's what I wanted to achieve. Then in your listview you just implement standard onItemClickListener instead of onTouch.